# Complex Integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Integrate:

$$
  \int_A^B z^3-5~dz 
$$

Where A = 2+i and B = 1-i are two points in complex plane.

How can this complex integral be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $$\int_\gamma f(z)\ dz = \int_0^1 f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'\ dt$$

where $\gamma$ is a parameterized curve between $A$ and $B$ such that $\gamma(0) = A$ and $\gamma(1) = B$. Choose any such $\gamma$ that makes your life easy. Perhaps a straight line between $A$ and $B$ will work: $$\gamma(t) = (1-t)A+tB.$$

The next step:

$$\gamma'(t) = B-A.\\
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 f(\gamma(t))\gamma'\ dt &= (B-A)\int_0^1 ((1-t)A+tB)^3-5\ dt \\
 &= (B-A) \int_0^1 ((B-A)t+A)^3\ dt - (B-A)\left. 5t\right|_0^1 \\
 &= -5(B-A)+(B-A)\int_0^1 (B-A)^3t^3+3(B-A)^2At^2 +3(B-A)A^2t + A^3\ dt \\
 &= \ldots
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: And, in particular, $f(z) = z^3 - 5$ is holomorphic, so the path chosen doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you please provide a full solution of this problem? So that I have one example to follow.

Comment: Surely you can do a basic real integral.